# Does injury affect the helping dice I grant to others?

Tags: burning-wheel

My character has a skill at B5. Let's say it's Navigation. Because I have five dice in the skill, if I use my Navigation to help another character, they'll gain +2D instead of the more typical +1D.

During a scuffle with pirates, my character sustains a nasty broken leg. This is a midi wound, worth -2D to all of my checks. If I try to help another character using my Navigation, do they still get the full +2D now, or only +1D because I'm injured?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes. Penalty dice from wounds *do* reduce your stats for the purposes of help (and FORKing) thresholds.

Helping dice are based on the exponent of your ability. BWG p. 36 (my emphasis throughout):

> ## Helping Dice
>
> If the exponent of the helping ability is 4 or lower, one die is given to the acting player as help. **If the exponent of the ability is 5 or higher**, two dice are granted.

Wound penalties reduce the dice you roll. BWG p. 488:

> ## Wounded Dice
>
> **Wound penalty dice are subtracted from stats, skills, Reflexes and Steel**. Health, mortal wound, Circles, Resources and Emotional Attributes like Faith are not affected. Do not refactor attributes or damage due to wounded stats. (Note that Reflexes is affected directly.)

The number of dice you roll when you actually use the ability *is* the "exponent." BWG p. 12:

> ## Exponent
>
> The number next to your character's stats, attributes, and skills **indicates how many dice to roll when that ability is called upon**. We here at Burning Wheel HQ call that number the exponent of the ability because **it is representative of the character's actual ability** in that area...

Therefore, wound dice reduce your effective exponent, which reduces the value of helping dice you grant.

FORKs are defined similarly to helping dice (see BWG p. 36), so wound penalties will also reduce the value of FORKs.

---

Based on https://forums.burningwheel.com/t/im-injured-does-this-affect-my-helping-dice/13458

Comment: Worth noting that it *affects* the number of dice, but doesn't actually *reduce* them unless you cross the exponent 5 threshold between 2 helping/FoRK dice and 1 die.